# npm install and npm start give error about github

Tags: node.js, git, github, npm

I recently set up a private repo on GitHub. Now when I try to do an npm install, `npm start`, neither commands no longer work. For the `npm install` I get

```
J:\workspace\epimss\angular2\ts\com-epimss.ng2.ts>npm install
npm ERR! git fetch -a origin (https://github.com/floridoo/gulp-sourcemaps.git) fatal: unable to access 'https://githu
b.com/floridoo/gulp-sourcemaps.git/': Failed to connect to github.com port 443: Timed out
npm ERR! git fetch -a origin (https://github.com/SitePen/remap-istanbul.git) fatal: unable to access 'https://github.
com/SitePen/remap-istanbul.git/': Failed to connect to github.com port 443: Timed out
npm ERR! fetch failed https://registry.npmjs.org/gulp-atom-electron/-/gulp-atom-electron-1.6.1.tgz
npm WARN retry will retry, error on last attempt: Error: connect ETIMEDOUT 23.235.39.162:443
npm ERR! fetch failed https://registry.npmjs.org/gulp-atom-electron/-/gulp-atom-electron-1.6.1.tgz
npm WARN retry will retry, error on last attempt: Error: connect ETIMEDOUT 23.235.39.162:443
npm ERR! Windows_NT 10.0.10586
npm ERR! argv "P:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "P:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "
install"
npm ERR! node v5.8.0
npm ERR! npm  v3.7.3
npm ERR! code 128

npm ERR! Command failed: git -c core.longpaths=true fetch -a origin
npm ERR! fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/floridoo/gulp-sourcemaps.git/': Failed to connect to github.com
port 443: Timed out
npm ERR!
npm ERR!
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this error at:
npm ERR!     <https://github.com/npm/npm/issues>

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     J:\workspace\epimss\angular2\ts\com-epimss.ng2.ts\npm-debug.log
```

I am new to github and just does not understand github should be involved trying to do an npm install or npm start.

I am using Webstorm IDE with the default git/github settings. I use to be able to do commit and push to the private repo but I can no longer do this.

Appreciate any help. Thanks.

Comment: Are you behind a proxy?

Comment: No - direct DSL connection to the internet. Github sent me an email about adding a public key to my SSH account. Could this be the problem as I will now have to use this key?

Answer (score 0):

If accessing GitHub through https fails for any reason, try first to check if that would work with ssh:

```
 url."ssh://git@github.com/".insteadOf https://github.com/
```

That means any git fetch done by npm module to github will be done with ssh protocol instead of https.